# Showing $\left \lvert \sum_{k=1}^n x_k y_k \right \rvert \le \frac{1}{\alpha} \sum_{k=1}^n x_k^2 + \frac{\alpha}{4} \sum_{k=1}^n y_k^2 $

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $\vec x, \vec y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\alpha > 0$. Show that $\left \lvert \sum_{k=1}^n x_k y_k \right \rvert \le \frac{1}{\alpha} \sum_{k=1}^n x_k^2 + \frac{\alpha}{4} \sum_{k=1}^n y_k^2 $.

$$LHS =  \left\lvert \vec x \cdot \vec y\right\rvert$$

\begin{align*}
RHS &= \frac{1}{4 \alpha}\left(4 \sum_{k=1}^n x_k^2 + \alpha^2 \sum_{k=1}^n y_k^2\right) 
\\&= \frac{1}{4 \alpha}\left(2\sqrt{ \sum_{k=1}^n x_k^2} - \alpha \sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^n y_k^2}\right) \left(2\sqrt{ \sum_{k=1}^n x_k^2} + \alpha \sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^n y_k^2}\right)
\\&= \frac{1}{4\alpha} \left( 2\left\lVert \vec x\right\rVert + \alpha\left\lVert \vec y\right\rVert\right)\left( 2\left\lVert \vec x\right\rVert - \alpha\left\lVert \vec y\right\rVert\right)
\end{align*}

Since the right hand side looks like a product of norms, it seems like Cauchy-Schwarz is the way to go, but I'm stumped as to how to proceed at this point. Any help on how to continue is appreciated.

Comment: When considering the RHS, you made a mistake going from the first line to the second line.

Comment: @KimJongUn How embarrassing. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inequality is actually only true for $\alpha>0$. In this case,
$$
\left(\frac{1}{\alpha}\sum_kx_k^2+\frac{\alpha}{4}\sum_ky_k^2\right)-\sum_k|x_ky_k|=\sum_k\frac{1}{\alpha}\left(|x_k|-\frac{\alpha}{2}|y_k|\right)^2\geq 0
$$
which implies
$$
\left(\frac{1}{\alpha}\sum_kx_k^2+\frac{\alpha}{4}\sum_ky_k^2\right)\geq\sum_k|x_ky_k|\geq\left|\sum_kx_ky_k\right|.
$$

Comment: I edited the question to reflect your comment. Thanks for noting that. I'm assuming you started with $\sum_k\frac{1}{\alpha}\left(|x_k|-\frac{\alpha}{2}|y_k|\right)^2\geq 0$ and then rexpressed it in terms of the right hand side. How did you know that inequality would get the job done? Is there a general expression that helped you get that?