# Prove that $\left| \sum_{j=1}^{n}a_j\bar{b_j} \right| \leq \frac{1}{\alpha}\sum_{j=1}^n|a_j|^2 + \frac{\alpha}{4}\sum_{j=1}^n|b_j|^2$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

I am stuck on the following proof and am really in need of some advice. I figured it would be similar to the cauchy-schwarz inequality proof but would like some help.

> Prove that for any $\alpha > 0$, and for any complex numbers $a_1,
> > a_2, \ldots, a_n$ and $b_1, b_2, \ldots, b_n$, we have $$\left|
> \sum_{j=1}^{n}a_j\bar{b_j} \right| \leq \frac{1}{\alpha}\sum_{j=1}^n|a_j|^2 +
>  \frac{\alpha}{4}\sum_{j=1}^n|b_j|^2$$

Any help or advice would greatly be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Are you completely sure that the coefficients should be as presented, as opposed to being symmetric (like $\frac{4}{\alpha}$ and $\frac{\alpha}{4}$)?

Comment: No, it is $\frac{1}{\alpha}$ as opposed to $\frac{4}{\alpha}$

Comment: The answer is [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/985179/showing-left-lvert-sum-k-1n-x-k-y-k-right-rvert-le-frac1-alpha-s?rq=1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

Since $|a_j|$ and $|b_j|$ are real positive numbers then
$$0\le\left(\frac{|a_j|}{\sqrt{\alpha}}-\frac{\sqrt{\alpha} |b_j|}{2}\right)^2$$
which implies $$|a_j\overline{b_j}|= |a_j||b_j| \le \frac{|a_j|^2}\alpha+\frac{\alpha |b_j|^2}4$$
Then
$$\sum_{j=1}^n|a_j\overline{b_j}|\le\frac1{\alpha}\sum_{j=1}^n|a_j|^2+\frac{\alpha}{4}\sum_{j=1}^n|b_j|$$
Now use the triangular inequality.